# What is different between MainActivity.this vs getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, android-context

I am trying ProgressDialog. But I am confused.

```
1. pd=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Fething data");
```

when I do use **(MainActivity.this)** then it is ok. But

```
2. pd=ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "", "Fething data");
```

When I do use **(getApplicationContext())** it is ERROR.

What is problem for this progressDialog?

What is different between  (`MainActivity.this`) vs (`getApplicationContext()`)

and when I use it the perfect time?

For `getApplicationContext()` Error is:

```
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at com.example.shikkok_services.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-09 15:05:37.453: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

> Which context to use?

There are two types of Context:

**Application context** is associated with the application and will always be the same throughout the life of application; it does not change. So if you are using `Toast`, you can use application context or even activity context (both) because `Toast` can be displayed from anywhere within your application and is not attached to a specific window. But there are many exceptions. One such exception is when you need to use or pass the activity context.

**Activity context** is associated with the activity and can be destroyed if the activity is destroyed; there may be multiple activities (more than likely) with a single application. Sometimes you absolutely need the activity context handle. For example, should you launch a new `Activity`, you need to use activity context in its `Intent` so that the newly-launched activity is connected to the current activity in terms of activity stack. However, you may also use application's context to launch a new activity, but then you need to set flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in intent to treat it as a new task.

Let's consider some cases:

`MainActivity.this` refers to the `MainActivity` context which extends `Activity` class but the base class (`Activity`) also extends `Context` class, so it can be used to offer activity context.

`getBaseContext()` offers activity context.

`getApplication()` offers application context.

`getApplicationContext()` also offers application context.

For more information please check this [link](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecampbell/cs65/lecture08/lecture08.html).

Comment: thanks for answer bro...@Zohra khan, but i have some confuse, MainActvity is Applecation and Actvitiy is context??

Comment: @user3515725 As the name suggest MainActivity is activity and its part of a application. There are various components in an application like service, activity, broadcast receiver et. al. MainActvity.this is activity context. Hope I am clear. Please accept my answer.

Comment: You can check androidhive.info for more on Android.

Comment: This part of your answer is just wrong: _"For example, should you launch a new activity, you need to use activity context in its Intent so that the new launching activity is connected to the current activity in terms of activity stack. However, you may use application's context too to launch a new activity but then you need to set flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in intent to treat it as a new task."_, The `Context` used to call `startActivity()` is relevant, however the `Context` used as the first parameter to the `Intent` constructor `new Intent(context, Foo.class)` can be any `Context`.

Comment: It would be useful if you would fix your answer to make this clear. A lot of people are very confused about this.

Comment: I'm implementing an `AlertDialog`, and it seems that `MainActivity.this` and `getBaseContext()` are not interchangeable. Is there anything equivalent to a `MainActivity.this`?

Answer (score 20):

- `MainActivity.this` only works if you are in an inner class of `MainActivity`.
- If you are in `MainActivity` itself, just use `this`.
- If you are in `another class` entirely, you need to pass it an `instance` of a `context` from the `Activity` you are in.

Hope this helps..

Comment: the first point may be wrong. I can pass `MainActivity.this` in the constructor of a another not inner class and it works

Answer (score 18):

This explanation is probably missing some subtle nuances but it should give you a better understanding of why one works but the other doesn't.

The difference is that `MainActivity.this` refers to the current activity (`context`) whereas the `getApplicationContext()` refers to the Application class.

The important differences between the two are that the Application class never has any UI associations and as such has no window token.

Long story short: For UI items that need context, use the Activity.

Comment: thansk @triggs for answare.application class is MainACtivity and current activity is xml layout??

Comment: No, both  the Application class and an Activity class can be considered a type of Context. The Application class can be thought of as the whole app but an Activity is what is currently on screen at any time and the xml layout is just the UI of an Activity.

Comment: could you define what is window token?

Comment: its just a ref to the Window, which is basically somewhere to put ui elements.
An Activity has a Window, so you can put Views in it, Application Context has no window, so there's no where to put Views.

Answer (score 7):

MainActivity.this refers to the the current activity (context) where the getApplicationContext() refers to the Application class.

The getApplicationContext() method return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.

MainActivity.this will change when activity destroyed and re-created, getApplicationContext() will change when the application killed and re-started.

Answer (score 1):

`mainActivity` gives the context of the current Activity. `context` depends on activity's lifecycle. `getApplicationContext()` gives the context of the application and depends on the application's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the developer.android.com says:

> Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.

In general, use ..Activity.this instead of getApplicationContext();

Further reading: [developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)

Comment: Actually in general it is better to use getApplicationContext() since it will less likey lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity.this` has more information. You can think of

`MainActivity.this` = `getApplicationContext()` + `UI related information`.

Why `getApplicationContext()` did not work here

```
2. pd=ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "", "Fething data");
```

is because the `ProgressDialog` needs UI information. `ProgressDialog` may or may not be full screen size. If it only takes a portion of the screen, what should the background be? Should it be black, white, or your `MainActivity`'s layout?

Which version of `context` to use depends on your use cases.

Non-UI-related `context` usages:

```
context.getFilesDir()  // File I/O
context.getColor()     // Preset values, strings, colors, pictures...

// create intent
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);

// start new activity
context.startActivity(intent);

...
```

UI-related `context` usages (i.e. `XXXActivity.this`):

```
// create Adapters for you UI element
myRecyclerViewAdapter = new myRecyclerViewAdapter(this);

// Make new dialogs, i.e. ProgressDialog, AlertDialog...
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)...

// Set current layout fullscreen to get rid of status bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

// Set attributes such as colors based on theme
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorBackground, typedValue, true);
@ColorInt int colorBasedOnTheme = typedValue.data;
```

When you pass `context` to other classes, the Non-UI version `context` (i.e. `getApplicationContext()`) will not expire because it lives as long as your application itself. But the UI version `context` (i.e. `XXXActivity.this`) will expire because it only lives as long as your `XXXActivity`. And if an object holds a `context`(`XXXActivity.this`) out-lives the original `XXXActivity`, there will be problems: memory leak, null point exception, undefined behaviours, etc.