# Android - what effect do different contexts have in code performance?

Tags: android, android-context

Context is a quite vague concept which I haven't grasped yet. I've seen cases where using the wrong context caused an error (getting a telephony service manager using an activity context instead of application context). In other occasions I've used different contexts for the same thing and nothing different happened.

If let's say I use `getApplicationContext()` everywhere what effect would that have performance-wise?

What is the "guide" to decide which context I should use in each occasion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext/22967165#22967165