# getBaseContext or getContext? How do they differ?

Tags: java, android

I noticed that inside my class that extends `View`, to get the screen size I have to use getContext

```
DisplayMetrics dispM = getContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = dispM.WidthPixels;
int height = dispM.HeightPixels;
```

if I wanted to do the same inside my Activity, I have to replace `getContext` with `getBaseContext`. Why is this the case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext/22967165#22967165

Comment: You can use Activity instance itself in Activity to find screen size, no need of getBaseContext() and in `View`, `getContext()` returns an instance of `Context` that you passed as parameter to view during its initialization i.e. at `new View(Context)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) Returns the context the view is currently running in. . Activity.

[getBaseContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29) : If you need access to a Context from within another context, you use this

Answer (score 5):

**[View.getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29):** Returns the context the view is currently running in.

**getBaseContext():** is the activity context itself. Even you can use `this`

Answer (score 2):

`View.getContext()` usually returns the context the view of current Activity. `ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()` is used while accessing a Context from within another context example Activity.

See at - [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)