# Unable to start AlertDialog box in android

Tags: java, android, dialog, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement an AlertDialogBox upon a button click. But I don't know for what reason the AlertDialog box wont start. Here what I have coded up till now :

```
netbalrefreshbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.netbalrefreshbtn);
        netbalrefreshbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(" Update Values")
                                  .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                                  {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                                    {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//                                      if(selecteditem == "Missed Call")
//                                      {
                                            String url = "tel:123456";
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                                            startActivity(intent);
//                                      }

                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                                {   
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                                    {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

I debugged the code and it is giving me this error :

```
03-23 13:59:36.450: E/AndroidRuntime(16221): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
03-23 13:59:36.450: E/AndroidRuntime(16221):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
03-23 13:59:36.450: E/AndroidRuntime(16221):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
03-23 13:59:36.450: E/AndroidRuntime(16221):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
03-23 13:59:36.450: E/AndroidRuntime(16221):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
03-23 13:59:36.450: E/AndroidRuntime(16221):    at com.techfrk.fetchinboxsms.IciciBank$1.onClick(IciciBank.java:86)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: The complete code is very long. I have implemented many additional things. This is the part that i added just now and it gave me an error !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is using `getApplicationContext()` as [context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). `AlertDialog.Builder` just needs activity context. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext#22967165) is an good explanation about [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android).

Replace

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

With

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is useful for you, please mark it as correct answer. Thanks !