# when click button, while connected wifi, show progress dialog on android

Tags: android

recently, When clicking the button WI-FI connect.

but I want during connecting , showing progress dialog

How can I do ?

```
protected final ScanResult mScanResult;
 private OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
 final WifiConfiguration config = Wifi.getWifiConfiguration(mWifiManager, mScanResult, mScanResultSecurity);
        boolean connResult = false;

if (config != null) {
       connResult = Wifi.connectToConfiguredNetwork(mFloating, mWifiManager, config, false);
    // I Think this part progress dialog. 
 }
        if (!connResult) {
            Toast.makeText(mFloating, R.string.toastFailed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mFloating.finish();
```

if finish connect wifi,
I want stop progress dialog
thanks.

Comment: There is Two way you can do it ..

Comment: What is the Two way ?

Comment: 1. Use Thread And 2.Use AsyncTAsk

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use async task

```
 class WIFIConfigurationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
            ProgressDialog dialog;
           protected final ScanResult mScanResult;



            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(Your_Activity.this);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
                dialog.setMessage(Constant.KEY_PLEASE_WAIT);
                dialog.show();
            }




            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
               //Background Task
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {
                try {
                    super.onPostExecute(response);
                    if (isCancelled())
                        return;

                    dialog.dismiss();
     private OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
 final WifiConfiguration config = Wifi.getWifiConfiguration(mWifiManager, mScanResult, mScanResultSecurity);
        boolean connResult = false;

if (config != null) {
       connResult = Wifi.connectToConfiguredNetwork(mFloating, mWifiManager, config, false);
    // I Think this part progress dialog. 
 }
        if (!connResult) {
            Toast.makeText(mFloating, R.string.toastFailed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mFloating.finish();
                   }
        }
```

May it work.(Not Tested)

Comment: thanks  this command. dialog = new ProgressDialog(Your_Activity.this); this part (your_activity)

Comment: How i code (your_activity) ?      this class is extends BaseContent

Comment: You can put your class name over here or public ProgressDialog (Context context), provide the context of the class

Comment: your_activity is the current activity in which you want to display progress dialog or use getApplicationContext()   but i suggest to use activity

Comment: I'm android beginner .    perhaps, in doInBackground    what write codE?

Comment: Use this....to understand http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: there is 3 main method of async task 1)on   preexecute you have to show process what you want to show user befor task done in Postexecute you have to show after process task done just like show TOAST "suceessful download" or any think in doinbackground you have to done main logicpart of your class just go on google search for it .

Comment: I keep trying, sorry

Comment: @hyunwook cho What is Problem now??

Comment: @JaymanJani thanks recently my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148043/how-catch-context-error-on-android?noredirect=1#comment59933646_36148043

Comment: @hyunwookcho study this one help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext