# Getting activity from context?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
        nearby_locations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(getApplicationContext()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

        }
    });
```

The `getApplicationContext()` in builder.build is underlined with an error saying it is looking for an activity not a context. I've tried casting but no luck, what should I do?

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext

Comment: your applicationContext is not an instanceof Activity so yes you cannot use getApplicationContext() where an Activity is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

Use

```
startActivityForResult(builder.build( ((Activity) view.getContext())), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

instead of

```
startActivityForResult(builder.build(getApplicationContext()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```