# What are these variables supposed to be? Firebase Authentication creating new account with email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an application using Google Firebase, and I used some of the code they provide for you to use, but I don't know what a few of these variables are. the variables are "auth_failed" and "EmailPasswordActivity".

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have a look at the [documentation for `Toast.makeText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context, int, int)), since these variables are passed into the first and second arguments of that method.

The first argument is documented as:

> `Context`: The context to use. Usually your [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) or [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) object.

So in this case it `EmailPasswordActivity.this` refers to the activity that the code is in. See [What is different between MainActivity.this vs getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext) for the `.this` suffix in this context.

The second argument is documented as:

> `resId    int`: The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be formatted text.

So this is a string resource (in your app's `strings.xml` file) that contains the text to display.

By the way: the [code snippet in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account) links to the [complete example on Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L120-L138).

Comment: I'm very confused as to what a context is or how to use/create one.

Comment: It's used by Android to constrain the life-cycle of (in this case) the Toast. It's not Firebase specific, so I'd read some more about it in the Android docs to get unconfused and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android.